# Dynamic header and footer color with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

With wkhtmltopdf, is there any way to vary the content of the footer based on the content present on the page? I have a document that change color every H1 and i want to take also the color of section so the header has the same color of the section. Is it possible to take this info in subst() function in header?

In the html content:

```
<div style="background-color:#101010">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
</div>
    content


<div style="background-color:#303030">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
</div>
    content
```

Thanks